# Memory issue while running processes from windows service written in C#

Tags: c#, service, process, out-of-memory

Memory issue while running processes from windows service written in C#:
I'm trying to run some processes using the next lines:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < runParamaters.Count; i++)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo pe = new ProcessStartInfo(runParamaters[i].command, runParamaters[i].parameters);
                pe.WorkingDirectory = runParamaters[i].folder;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pe);
 }
```

While running this loop from command-line exe or winform exe, it works fine.  But running it from service (on it's "start" function) - some of the processes couldn't allocate memory and failed.

Any idea why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Process can cause a lot of problems (with memory too). Maybe you should reconsider using Threads instead. Also... paste your error stack :)

Comment: tnx,  Morasiu.  I have no error stack - some of the exe files that are loaded within this simply reports "can't allocate memory" and are not running.  I need to run some processes on computer "turn on" without login, some of it are very old files. So threads will not help me.

Comment: Ohh... I see. How many processes are you trying to run? Also maybe Windows Scheduler (or Linux Cron) will solve your problem

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (this will include the exact processes being invoked).

Comment: `can't allocate memory` At the risk of asking a stupid question, is the machine out of memory?

Comment: no,  mjwills.  while using "normal" exe file to run it, no problem with memory at all.

Comment: That isn't what I asked. I mean, when you ran it through a service, were you monitoring the memory usage?

Comment: How many processes are you spawning? You may be hitting the  default desktop heap size for services, which is smaller than that for applications.

Comment: tnx, spodger. I can run 5.  currently I'm trying to run 7 (the last two can't run).  for testing - it's same exe file again and again.

Comment: Have a look this - the solution may be useful. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bdfb388-abf2-48c6-b587-fdff23599db6/child-process-limits-in-service-context-and-conhostexe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the OS allocates less heap memory for services.  The solution was to edit the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems\Windows
using regedit in order to set more heap.  Thank a lot to spodger.

Comment: what to change there?

Comment: The struction of this key is:
%SystemRoot%\system32\csrss.exe ObjectDirectory=\Windows SharedSection=1024,20480,768 Windows=On SubSystemType=...hreads=16

the next substring shuould be changed:
SharedSection=xxxx,yyyy,zzzz

Where:

    xxxx specifies the maximum size of the system-wide heap (in kilobytes)
    yyyy specifies the size of each desktop heap
    zzzz specifies the size of the desktop heap that is associated with a noninteractive Windows instance
@IyadBacdounes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of program you are trying to run, but I'd try this:

```
pe.CreateNoWindow = false;
pe.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Comment: Nop.  the UseShellExecute made error "bad path", and CreateNoWindow  had no effect.

Comment: Just guessing now, but you might want to try to modify one setting on your windows  service configuration (in Services). Open Services windows, right click on your service, select 'Properties', then 'Log on', check the 'Allow service to interact with desktop' checkbox...and see if it helps